# Controlling TI OMAP l138 frequency leads to "Division by zero in kernel"

Tags: linux, division, omap

My team is trying to control the frequency of an Texas Instruments OMAP l138. The default frequency is 300 MHz and we want to put it to 372 MHz in a "complete" form: we would like not only to change the default value to the desired one (or at least configure it at startup), but also be capable of changing the value at run time.

Searching on the web about how to do this, we found an article which tells that one of the ways to do this is by an "echo" command:

```
echo 372000 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed
```

We did some tests with this command and it runs fine with one problem: sometimes the first call to this echo command leads to a error message of "Division by zero in kernel":

[image: PrintScreen with error message]

In my personal tests, this error appeared always in the first call to the echo command. All the later calls worked without error. If, then, I reset my processor and calls the command again, the same problem occurs: the first call leads to this error and later calls work without problem.

So my questions are: what is causing this problem? And how could I solve it? (Obviously the answer "always type it twice" doesn't count!)

(Feel free to mention other ways of controlling the OMAP l138's frequency at real time as well!)

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you have division by zero in **davinci_spi_cpufreq_transition()** function. Somewhere in this function (or in some function that's being called in **davinci_spi_cpufreq_transition**) there is a buggy division operation which tries to divide by some variable which is (in your case) has value of 0. And this is obviously error case which should be handled properly in code, but in fact it isn't.

It's hard to tell which code exactly leads to this, because I don't know which kernel you are using. It would be much more easier if you can provide link to your kernel repository. Although I couldn't find **davinci_spi_cpufreq_transition** in upstream kernel, I found it [here](https://gitorious.org/hawkboard/linux-omapl1).

**davinci_spi_cpufreq_transition()** function appears to be in [drivers/spi/davinci_spi.c](https://gitorious.org/hawkboard/linux-omapl1/source/2acf935c01b9adb50164d421c40cdc5862b9e143:drivers/spi/davinci_spi.c#L866-882). It calls [davinci_spi_calc_clk_div() function](https://gitorious.org/hawkboard/linux-omapl1/source/2acf935c01b9adb50164d421c40cdc5862b9e143:drivers/spi/davinci_spi.c#L141-165). There are 2 division operations there. First is:

```
prescale = ((clk_rate / hz) - 1);
```

And second is:

```
if (hz < (clk_rate / (prescale + 1)))
```

One of them is probably causing "division by zero" error. I propose you to trace which one is that by modifying **davinci_spi_calc_clk_div()** function in next way (just add lines marked as "+"):

```
    static void davinci_spi_calc_clk_div(struct davinci_spi *davinci_spi)
    {
        struct davinci_spi_platform_data *pdata;
        unsigned long clk_rate;
        u32 hz, cs_num, prescale;

        pdata = davinci_spi->pdata;
        cs_num = davinci_spi->cs_num;
        hz = davinci_spi->speed;
        clk_rate = clk_get_rate(davinci_spi->clk);
+       printk(KERN_ERR "### hz = %u\n", hz);
        prescale = ((clk_rate / hz) - 1);
        if (prescale > 0xff)
            prescale = 0xff;

+       printk("### prescale + 1 = %u\n", prescale + 1UL);
        if (hz < (clk_rate / (prescale + 1)))
            prescale++;

        if (prescale < 2) {
            pr_info("davinci SPI controller min. prescale value is 2\n");
            prescale = 2;
        }

        clear_fmt_bits(davinci_spi->base, 0x0000ff00, cs_num);
        set_fmt_bits(davinci_spi->base, prescale << 8, cs_num);
    }
```

My guess -- it's "hz" variable which is 0 in your case. If it's so, you also may want to add next debug line to **davinci_spi_setup_transfer()** function:

```
        if (!hz)
                hz = spi->max_speed_hz;

+       printk(KERN_ERR "### setup_transfer: setting speed to %u\n", hz);
        davinci_spi->speed = hz;
        davinci_spi->cs_num = spi->chip_select;
```

With all those modifications made, rebuild your kernel and you will probably get the clue why you have that "div by zero" error. Just look for lines started with "###" in your kernel boot log. In case you don't know what to do next -- attach those debug lines and I will try to help you.

Comment: thanks for the answer, Sam. As soon as our priorities are gone, we will work on this problem and I'll return with the feedback.